# numpy array - choosing maximum based on multiple rows

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a function bestcolumn for a 2-dimensional numpy array that will do the following 
- choose the column with maximum value in row 0, if there are multiple values with the maximum in row 0, between them choose the column with maximum value in column 1 and then apply the same with column 2.

In the example below, 4 is the max value in row 0 but there are three columns  0,1,2 with the same value 4 so we search in row 1 cols 0,1,2. The max is 5 in col 1,2. We then search in col 2 for the tiebreaker and choose col 2

Is there a way to achieve this using numpy's vectorized operations (instead of using for loops and if/else statements)?

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.asarray([[4,4,4,3],
                [3,5,5,7],
                [2,3,4,10]])
```

Comment: Not totally numpy but this would do: `sorted([tuple(a) for a in A.T])[-1]` gives `(4,5,4)`.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [numpy.lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) but it sort all columns not only find the maximal one.

```
np.lexsort(-A.T)[0]
# 2
```